# Aggregate Root Id

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, symfony4, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am using CQRS/Event Sourcing for a project and it is mainly for learning and discover new things.

And i am a little bit confused with aggregate root ids. Not on how they work but how to write them correctly. So let me explain:

For each aggregate root, i have an id and this id is generated by the *ramsey/uuid* library. I've created a custom **Value Object** called **Uuid** that's wrap all the logic of the uuid. Here is some code about it:

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as BaseUuid;

/**
 * @var StringValueObject
 */
private $value;

/**
 * Uuid constructor.
 *
 * @param null|string $value
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
protected function __construct(?string $value = null)
{
    $uuid_str = BaseUuid::uuid4();

    if (null !== $value) {
        $pattern = '/' . BaseUuid::VALID_PATTERN . '/';

        if (!\preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
            throw new InvalidNativeArgumentException($value, array('Uuid string'));
        }

        $uuid_str = $value;
    }

    $this->value = StringValueObject::fromNative(\strval($uuid_str));
}
```

My concern now is when i create an aggregate root, i need naturally to choose the type of my ID, 2 choices:

1. Type of Uuid (the value object above)
2. A new Value Object (UserId, PropertyId, etc) that inherits of the Uuid Value Object.

For the moment, i use the first solution but i think the second is better mainly for the Ubiquitous Language, UserID, PropertyId is more meaningful that just Uuid.

Also, when a user request a resources, it is a good thing to expose the uuid in the url, is there another way to do that? Should i create another field in my aggregate root, a sort of id that we can expose in the url to access to a given resource?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Good question Thibsss13. There are a few things to bear in mind about AGID (Aggregate Root Id).

First, they are generally an implementation detail. A practical necessity, and they don't necessarily fit into the UL. But it's clearly better if they do but it needs to come from the business, not you the developer.

Regarding which method to chose to generate the UUID. In my opinion, it doesn't matter. Just go simple and quick - so long as it is unique!

Top tip - Create the AGID before you instantiate or new up the AG. Preferably as close to the client as possible. That way you know what to look out for on the read side.

For a reasonable overview of how it typically all fits together check out [A CQRS Step-By-Step Overview](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/)